# Example of skew (non-intersecting) lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, intersection-theory, projective-varieties

In Hartshorne's "*Algebraic Geometry*", exercise I-3.7(a) asks us to show that any two curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$ have non-empty intersection. This lead me to think about whether this was generalizable to higher dimensional projective space, $\mathbb{P}^n$ for $n \geq 3$.

In particular, I read in an article that one can already find skew lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$ so this non-empty intersection principle does not hold for higher dimensions. I was wondering whether there were any examples of this?

Hartshorne later suggests in I-7 Theorem 7.2 a criterion for this not to be the case.

However, assuming we took two lines (1-dimensional varieties) in $\mathbb{P}^3$, of the general form:

$L_1=V(a_1X+b_1Y+c_1Z+d_1W)$

$L_2=V(a_2X+b_2Y+c_2Z+d_2W)$

wouldn't it be true that the point $[0:0:0:0] \in V(L_1,L_2)$, so the intersection would be non-empty? Is there an example where this would not be the case?

Thanks in advance and sorry!

Comment: (I think) in projective space need at least one coordinate nonzero. [then can "normalize" by dividing through by length...]

Comment: By the way, the general principal at work here is that if $a + b = n$, then a general pair of varieties in $\mathbb P^n$ with dimensions $a$ and $b$ will intersect in a finite set. If $a + b > n$, the intersection will be positive-dimensional, while if $a + b < n$ you can have basically anything happen (since the varieties can be disjoint, or they could be the same variety and $X \cap X = X$).

Comment: One way to visualize $\mathbb{P}^3$ is as $\mathbb{R}^3$ except that two things intersect if they have the same "slope" asymptotically. So what you want is two lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that aren't parallel. (of course it's a lie to think of the reals when the underlying field is algebraically closed, but it's also a lie that these are "lines" if you want to visualize $\mathbb{C}^3$, pick your poison).

Answer (score 1):

Remember, $\Bbb P^n$ is $\Bbb A^{n+1}\setminus\{(0,\dots,0)\}$ up to scaling, so $[0:\dots:0]$ is not an element of $\Bbb P^n$. One easy example of two skew lines in $\Bbb P^3$ are $\{[a:b:0:0]\mid [a:b]\in\Bbb P^1\}$ and $\{[0:0:c:d]\mid [c:d]\in\Bbb P^1\}$.